# Extracting duplicate values from a defaultdict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a `defaultdict` defined as follows:

```py
devicedict1=collections.defaultdict(list)
```

The device dict contains an index key, and double values as follows:

```py
{0: ['9085', '9084'], 1: ['9084', '5684'], 2: ['9084', '3707'], 3: ['9084', '3707'], 4: ['3707', '9084'], 5: ['9084', '3707'], 6: ['3707', '9084'], 7: ['9084', '5684'], 8: ['9084', '3707'], 9: ['9084', '3707'], 10: ['9084', '3707'], 11: ['9084', '5684'], 12: ['3707', '9084']
```

I want to extract the tuples (value, value) that appear the most, and print them.

I've tried using Counter and items().

```py
e=Counter(devicedict1.items())
print(e)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. It should give us the following results:

```
['9084', '3707']:30
['9084', '5684']:10
```

Comment: Where do the values `30` and `10` come from? Pls show the entire sample input

Comment: 30 means, 30 duplicate records and 10 the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) if you `map` the values in the dictionary to tuples, given that unlike lists, *tuples are hashable*. To get the `n` tuples that appear the most there is the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method:

```
n = 3
Counter(map(tuple, devicedict1.values())).most_common(n)
# [(('9084', '3707'), 6), (('9084', '5684'), 3), (('3707', '9084'), n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Counter`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter

data = {0: ['9085', '9084'], 1: ['9084', '5684'], 2: ['9084', '3707'], 3: ['9084', '3707'], 4: ['3707', '9084'], 5: ['9084', '3707'], 6: ['3707', '9084'], 7: ['9084', '5684'], 8: ['9084', '3707'], 9: ['9084', '3707'], 10: ['9084', '3707'], 11: ['9084', '5684'], 12: ['3707', '9084']}
c = Counter(map(tuple, data.values()))
print(c.most_common(2))
```

**Output:**

```
[(('9084', '3707'), 6), (('9084', '5684'), 3)]
```